# Regarding FOPEN in C

Tags: c, fopen

I am having a problem regarding FOPEN in C.

I have this code which reads a particular file from a directory

```
FILE *ifp ;
char directoryname[50];
char result[100];
char *rpath = "/home/kamal/samples/pipe26/divpipe0.f00001";
char *mode = "r";

ifp = fopen("director.in",mode); %director file contains path of directory

while (fscanf(ifp, "%s", directoname) != EOF) 
 {
 strcpy(result,directoname);  /* Path of diretory /home/kamal/samples/pipe26 */
 strcat(result,"/");          /* front slash for path */
 strcat(result,name);         /* name of the file divpipe0.f00001*/
 }
```

Till this point my code works perfectly creating a string which looks " /home/kamal/samples/pipe26/divpipe0.f00001 ".

The problem arises when I try to use the 'result' to open a file, It gives me error. Instead if I use 'rpath' it works fine even though both strings contain same information.

```
 if (!(fp=fopen(rpath,"rb")))     /* This one works fine */
  {
    printf(fopen failure2!\n"); 
    return;
 }


  if (!(fp=fopen(result,"rb")))     /* This does not work */
  {
    printf(fopen failure2!\n"); 
    return;
  }
```

Could some one please tell why I am getting this error ?

Comment: You should *always* test against failure of `fopen`

Comment: You should use  `perror` or `strerror`  not just a `printf`on failure of `fopen`

Comment: In the question, there is a trailing space on the string.  Print your `result` string with colons on either side to ensure that it does not have extra whitespace (eg, a trailing newline).

Comment: @WilliamPursell : Yes I did what you said and found that my result has white spaces.  "/home/kamal/samples/pipe26/divpipe0.f00001           ". Can you tell me how do I get ride of them ?

Comment: Trim it from `name`.  You haven't shown the code where `name` is assigned.

Comment: @WilliamPursell :  The variable name is assigned some where very deep inside the other code.  I can make a copy of it.  what should I do to trim a string ? Thank you

Comment: Just replace the first trailing space with a '\0'.

Answer (score 1):

I think you mean `char result[100];`; i.e. without the asterisk. (Ditto for `directoryname`.)

You're currently stack-allocating an array of 100 pointers. This will not end well.

Note that `rpath` and `mode` point to *read-only* memory. Really you should use `const char*` for those two literals.

Comment: Hi, I recomplied the code with 'char result[100] '  and 'directoryname[100]' without pointers, but I still get the same error. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error is the array 'char* result[100]', here you are allocating an array of 100 pointers to strings, not 100 bytes / characters, which was your intent.